# PHP if statement with German umlauts

Tags: plugins, php, wp-cli

Im sure someone can help here pls. I have an problem with German Umlauts (ä,ü,ö)

Code

```
$wppost_interpret = $this->data['track']['itunes']['artistName'];
$wppost_interpret_title = $this->data['track']['itunes']['trackName'];

$wppost_exist_1 = exec("wp db query 'SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE \"$wppost_interpret_title - $wppost_interpret\" LIMIT 1' --path='/var/www/ccc.com/htdocs' --quiet");

if ($wppost_exist_1 == "$wppost_interpret_title - $wppost_interpret") {
// nothing
echo "true";
} else {
echo "false";
// do something
};
```

The full script is working like I want. But when it coming to Titles like "Die Hände zum Himmel", my output is always "false".

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of your database collation. There are numerous questions on StackOverflow about this sort of thing. Your question may get closed or migrated as it's not on-topic for wordpress.stackexchange.com;

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607130/mysql-treats-%C3%85%C3%84%C3%96-as-aao), or perhaps ask there instead.

Also, why are you not using the WordPress [WP_Query class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) to return posts?

Comment: This script is not directly in an Wordpress install. So I using WP-CLI to get the Data that I need. I think this Topic is in the right Category. Its Wordpress related.

I solved it now and added the Query the BINARY part like: SELECT post_title FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title LIKE BINARY \"$wppost_interpret_title - $wppost_interpret\" LIMIT 1

And formatted the output with the help of "utf8_encode".

Its working now like expected.

Comment: Glad you got it working You can post that as an answer if you like (and accept it), so that other people with a similar problem can be helped.